# SQL Server Replication - Synchronize single article

Tags: sql-server, replication

I am using Merge Replication to synchronize 2 databases, but the client came up now with a requirement that I think it's not possible to support using Merge Replication.
What he wants is: Everytime a change is made on database B, this needs to immediately go to database A. On the other hand, the changes done in database A should only be applied on B once a day.

I have researched a lot, and I think Transactional Replication with Updatable Subscription (Immediate) is the way to go, but I would like to keep using merge replication if possible.

Is there any way to meet this requirement using Merge Replication?

Answer (score 0):

Would something as simple as having a trigger on the table in database B that fires off the sync process work?

Comment: You are suggesting me to keep merge replication AND add a trigger to take care of this special table that needs immediate sync? I've been thinking about that and it's not a bad idea.

Comment: That's my suggestion. It's a little hackish, but we live in a world of less than ideal solutions...